# Edit .xml using simple requests

Tags: android, android-layout

What I need to do is, give the app into hands of a non-programmer and make it simple for him to edit the xml and java files. To do that I thought maybe sending a simple request (such as, add product(name, description, price)) through some portal could edit the xml file and java file.  For example, I need to repeat the similar code every time a new product request is posted:

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/hw5"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hardware 5"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="$-"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
LinearLayout hw5;
hw5 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.hw5);
hw5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     Intent hw5 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Hw5.class);
     startActivity(hw5);
}
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you might be looking for here is a domain-specific XML file paired with an appropriate XSL transformation. The XML file that the non-technical person would be editing would define the business entities, relationships with them and potential actions performed on them. The XSL transformation would convert this into application code at build time.

While this is not a common approach, it is rather robust. Keep in mind tho, that such an approach is difficult to maintain and requires that your business logic is mature enough before implementation.